# How to reduce size of VB6 compiled executable?

Tags: vb6, compilation, exe

My VB6 program currently compiles to a 6MB executable.  I guess this is not really a problem with today's machines, but I would like to reduce it to under a megabyte.

What would the best way to do this?

Note: I have already tried doing *"Optimise for small code"*. This actually increased the EXE to 16MB!

If the solution is to separate some of the code into a separate DLL, what would be the best way to do this?  Should you leave all the forms in the EXE and put all the classes and modules in a DLL?  How do I know what in particular is causing the EXE to be so big?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the size. Splitting the code into DLLs is a good idea because it makes the project more manageable. Split it into logical self contained chunks rather than trying to make each chunk a particular size.

Comment: You don't think 6MB is too big for an EXE?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't worry about the size. Is it actually causing a problem? 6 megabytes isn't large these days, whether you're thinking about disk space, download time, or whatever. But you might want to split the code up to make it more manageable.

Comment: It's not causing any problems that I'm aware of, but when I see commerical apps such as VS whose EXEs are less than half a megabyte then it does make me bit concerned.

Comment: If you mean Visual Studio, the accompanying dependencies are hundreds of megabytes. So why worry?

Comment: @MarkJ: The size of EXEs seems to be kept well below 1MB. IE is ~730KB for example. There must be a good reason for this, because they could fill them up with as much as they want.

Comment: @GaryJones Check out my answer regarding compiling to P-Code, doing virtual exe compression (auto decompressed into memory when run only, remains as exe file), checking your .ico file sizes, using #IF directives to remove code & strings that the end user will never see/use/need and (as others have suggested) checking the images/sounds/videos & other resources that are embedded into your compiled VB6 EXE application file. I'm certain you can get your 6MB file down to anywhere between 200KB's - 500KB's (maximum) WITHOUT losing any functionality or making drastic changes. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Note that Visual Studio was built to be very modular. `devenv.exe` is little more than a stub and container to the rest of the libraries and languages.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely your code is not the problem, the resources are.  For instance, you probably have a large image plopped in a picturebox control on some form.  The image is saved as an uncompressed bitmap and that is what's contributing to the size of the EXE.  If that is your issue, move the image out of the app and into an external JPG.

Another example is if you have a bunch of reports in the app and each of the reports has the company logo in the header/footer.  Centralize the logo elsewhere and access it via a helper method.

Comment: I'd say the same. If you are not sure about the sizes, check the size of the .frx and .res files in your project folder.

Answer (score 1):

I must say, compiles to P-Code, it should be in the Make tab advanced options somewhere. It reduces my EXE from 700 KB's to 200 KB's (big difference). Then, do the image/sound/other resources reductions as others have suggested.

Also, check your icons! Some icons can get up to 250KB's PER ICON - and if you have several forms with several different icons, then this can add up. A typical modern icon is about 50 KB's, but can be way more, as different icon resolutions are stored for different colour and display settings, so in one icon .ico file, you'll have 4 icon images for high graphics display, another 4 for a lower graphics display (256 bit colour) and another 4 for 16 bit colour etc. and you might end up having 16 - 20 icon images in one .ico file for just one form. You can remove the icon images like static pics in a series of gif images, they can be removed frame by frame (or icon pic by icon pic in this case) and 16 bit and 256 bit colour options can be removed as well.

Now, to my next recommendation, use #IF directives to remove any debugging/reporting texts that are in your application that will never be seen by any of the users (strings that are not needed by the end users) and/or any additional functions you use for testing/debugging or reporting that is not necessary to the end user... you can remove all of this using the #IF directive. You can turn all of your #IF directives (conditional compile arguments) on/off in one shot by setting a constant Boolean in your properties window, more info on this can be found in one of my posts re #IF directives and file size here: [When I use Conditional Compilation Arguments to Exclude Code, why doesn't VB6 EXE file size change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320285/when-i-use-conditional-compilation-arguments-to-exclude-code-why-doesnt-vb6-ex) (also, there are many great StackOverflow posts describing how to do conditional compilation using #IF THEN #ELSE #END IF directives, just search).

Finally, to my last recommendation, after you've reduced your file size by 3 to 4 times its size using p-code compilation alone, you can reduce it by another 3 to 4 times using a decent EXE compressor! So, just using p-code and exe compression I'm pretty sure you can get your 6MB file down under 600KB's (without even doing any of the other optimizations relating to #IF directives, icon files and other image/sound resources). Because p-code compilation is NOT compression related, by adding exe compression, you can get a huge file size reduction without losing the .exe extension. By using a good compressor, I'm not talking about changing it to a .zip file or a .rar file or anything. After compression, it will still remain as a .exe while also being compressed, and people can run it and use it normally without noticing any difference, so, as soon as your exe is executed, it decompresses in memory and loads into memory all on the fly, and when you close the application, nothing changes (file size still the same, small & compressed). PECompact GUI version is a good option, might even be available on some torrent sizes, + several free options in terms of programs that do this.

To sum up, do p-code compilation from your VB6 make tabs advanced / compilation section, look at the difference. Then do each optimization, recompile and note the file size difference and you'll get a good idea what the impact of each change would provide. Repeat until you've tried all options. Biggest differences will come from p-code compilation and exe compression. Of course, resources/icons/#IF directives you should try after the p-code & compression options, since p-code & compression are the easiest and will most likely reduce your file size down to 10% of its original size (10 x difference combined).

Finally, let me know how you get along, I am curious now how it turns out. Also, p-code runs on all locations/PC's that have visual basic runtime, so there is really no catch. They say p-code code runs a little bit slower than normal compiled code, but the difference is so small that it is not noticeable at all. Given that PC's are so fast now days, the running speed difference is even harder to notice (much more negligible) than it was when VB6 first came out, so I really would consider it to be the ultimate free lunch especially if file size is important to you.

Let me know how it goes or if you have any additional questions. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing any new code, you should really be writing for VB.Net.

One of the many advantages of VB.Net over VB6 (outside of the obvious "VB6 isn't supported anymore") is the large set of ready-to-use code built in to the .Net runtime (which results in a correspondingly smaller .exe).

Outside of that, one thing that can cause large .exe's is using lots of bitmaps.  You might want to see if that's the culprit.  If so, you can get a HUGE reduction in filesize just by loading images at runtime instead.

Comment: It's true that VB6 is not in continued development but MS have said that even Win8 will support VB6 apps.

Comment: In the interests of accuracy: the VB6 IDE isn't supported any more, but the VB6 runtime is fully supported. See our [VB6 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vb6/info) for details and references. In addition, if the exe is already 6 megabytes, then it's a bit late to advise starting from scratch in VB.net

Answer (score 0):

6 mb seems large for a vb6 application. 
It is possible you have some sound or image resources in the application

For images ... use some utility such as Photoshop to reduce the size.
Also load the images at run time. This should give you a smaller exe

Answer (score 0):

You can try this compressor.

http://www.exetools.com/files/compressors/win/petite22.zip

Secure and compress your Vb6 exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this compressor:[UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/). It's free and fast.