# When I use Conditional Compilation Arguments to Exclude Code, why doesn't VB6 EXE file size change?

Tags: performance, compiler-construction, vb6, compilation, compiler-optimization

Basically, when declaring Windows API functions in my VB6 code, there comes with these many constants that need to be declared or used with this function, in fact, usually most of these constants are not used and you only end up using one of them or so when making your API calls, so I am using **Conditional Compilation Arguments** to exclude these (and other things) using something like this:

```
IncludeUnused = 0 : Testing = 1
```

(this is how I set two conditional compilation arguments (they are of Boolean type by default).

So, many unused things are excluded like this:

```
#If IncludeUnused Then
' Some constant declarations and API declarations go here, sometimes functions
' and function calls go here as well, so it's not just declarations and constants
#End If
```

I also use a similar wrapper using the **Testing** Boolean declared in the **Conditional Compilation Argument** input field in the VB6 Properties windows "Make" tab. The **Testing** Boolean is used to display message boxes and things like that when I am in testing mode, and of course, these message boxed are removed (not displayed) if I have **Testing** set to 0 (and it is obviously 1 when I am Testing).

The problem is, I tried setting **IncludeUnused** and **Testing** to 0 and 1 and visa versa, a total of four (4) combinations, and no matter what combination I set these values to, the output EXE file size for my VB6 EXE does not change! It is always 49,152 when compiled to Native Code using Fast Code, and when using Small Code.

Additionally, if I compile to p-code under the four (4) combinations of **Testing** and **IncludeUnused**, i always end up with the file size 32,768 no matter what.

This is driving me crazy, since it is leading me to believe that no change is actually occuring, even though it is. Why is it that when segments of code are excluded from compilation, the file size is still the same? What am I missing or doing wrong, or what have I miscalculated?

I have considered the option that perhaps VB6 automatically does not compile code which is not used into the final output EXE, but I have read from a few sources that this is not true, in that, if it's included, it is compiled (correct me if I am wrong), and if this is right, then there is no need to use the **IncludeUnused** Boolean to remove unused code...?

If anyone can shed some light on these thoughts, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It could well be that the size difference is very small and that the exe size is padded to the next 512 or 1024 byte alignment. Try compressing the exe's with zip and see if the zip-file sizes differ.

Comment: VB6 executable sizes are padded to 4KB blocks, so if the code difference is small it will make no difference to the executable.

Comment: @GTG thanks for your input, it turns out you were right, trying bits and pieces moves the file size in 4KB blocks up or down, and when compressing (using a particular packager that applies compression to the VB6 EXE), the files are saved in 512 byte blocks, being 8 times less than the 4KB blocks VB6 uses, hence the differences in actual/real size became somewhat evident when I applied compression to VB6 EXE's with different Conditional Compilation Arguments. Of the 4 combinations, two of them were the same, one was 512 bytes greater than the two, and another 512 bytes less than the two.

Comment: @GTG Of course, if anyone has any additional info on this, or even information on why it is designed this way etc... feel free to provide an official answer and I will acknowledge and upvote where appropriate. To GTG in particular, please feel free to copy/paste your answer as an official answer, so I can upvote and "accept" as answer so that you may be awarded the rep points you are due.

Comment: @VilleKrumlinde Comments to GTG apply to you as well, your idea on compressing to see the true file size difference was an excellent example and logic by deduction, feel free to copy/paste as an official answer so I (and others) can vote on it.

Comment: VB6 itself does not produce the EXE. Compiling and linking a minimal program using the 6.x LINK.EXE that installs into the VB98 folder I get a 16,384 byte EXE. Compiling and linking the same program with a newer 8.x LINK.EXE I get a 6,656 byte EXE.

Comment: @Bob77 Are you saying there is a 8.x LINK.EXE for VB6, or is the 8.x LINK.EXE only for VB.NET (being, VB.NET 8/VB8)...? Why is the EXE smaller for 8.x LINK.EXE? If the 8.x LINK.EXE is for VB6, can I update the LINK.EXE file and get a more efficient EXE production? Any Pro's or Con's for doing this or does 8.x LINK.EXE only work for Visual Basic .NET version 8?

Comment: .Net only parasitizes tools like this from the Windows SDK, which is where LINK.EXE comes from, not from Visual Studio.  As far as I know the newer versions of LINK.EXE are just better about packing things together and leaving less "dead air" in the resulting EXE.  I haven't found any downside, the resulting VB6 EXEs still run on Win95 with no problems.  So install a recent Windows SDK and then copy over LINK.EXE and the DLLs it uses after renaming the old version in your VB6 Program Files directory.

Comment: @Bob77 So a quick copy-over should do teh trick without any issues? Cool I will try this. I'm assuming I will only need to copy over the DLL's from new version which have matching names in the old version's directory, and that there are no additional DLL's with new names I need to be aware of...?

Comment: There are a couple of DLLs that the old version did not use. Worst case you'll find out which ones when you try using it and get missing DLL errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could well be that the size difference is very small and that the exe size is padded to the next 512 or 1024 byte alignment. Try compressing the exe's with zip and see if the zip-file sizes differ.

Comment: Thank you, the compression idea did produce results as you predicted, where the file size (compressed) was different under different #IF directives even though the uncompressed file size was the same. Now, my final question, are VB6 EXE's padded in 4KB intervals or is the padding value smaller than 4KB's? thx.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand what a compiler does.  The output of the VB6 compiler is *code*.  Constants are merely place holders for values, they are not code.  The compiler adds them to its symbol table.  And when it later encounters a statement in your code that uses the constant then it *replaces* the constant by its value.  That statement produces the exact same code whether you use a constant or hard-code the value in the statement.

So this automatically implies that if you never actually use the constant anywhere then there is no difference at all in the generated code.  All that you accomplished by using the #If is to keep the compiler's symbol table smaller.  Which is something that makes very little sense to do, the actual gain from compilation speed you get is not measurable.  Symbol tables are implemented as hash tables, they have O(1) amortized complexity.

You use constants only to make your code more readable.  And to make it easy to change a constant value if the need ever arises.  By using #If, you actually made your code *less* readable.

Comment: I interpret the question as "does the VB compiler perform dead-code-elimination" which I assume it does. Additionally if using preprocessor directives such as #if..#endif then the compiler won't look at the code when the #if evaluates to false. Which will reduce generated code size.

Comment: Using #if around constant declarations does *not* reduce generated code size.  Constants are not code.  This is why the OP asked the question.

Comment: Now I understand your answer and you are of course right. However he did also write "sometimes functions and function calls go here as well" so I read it as he use ifdefs around code too.

Comment: I use #IF to turn a series of constants off and on (ie: if #if is true, use these const values, if false, use the other const values). I understand how const values work, and that they are symbolic. However, the majority of what lies in my #IF expressions are functions calls and actual code, which is important for me to include when testing and doing reporting (all the debugging/reporting strings and code take up a lot of size), which is another reason I use #IF to turn testing mode on and off...

Comment: @VilleKrumlinde Also, I have functions that are not used (but are not commented out either) that I do not want to delete. So, because I am assuming these functions are compiled into the target EXE (even though they are not called or referenced anywhere else) I wrap them in an #IF checking the "IncludeUnused" boolean [#IF IncludeUnused Then], so if I set IncludeUnused to 0 in properties, then these unused functions are not compiled, allowing me to keep them in my code viewer without deletion but without adding to file size. Do I need to do this or does VB6 auto exclude unused functions/subs?thx

Answer (score 2):

You can't test runtime data in conditional compilation directives.

These directives use expressions made up of literal values, operators, and CC constants.  One way to set constant values is:

```
#Const IncludeUnused = 0
#Const Testing = 1
```

You can also define them via Project Properties for IDE testing.  Go to the Make tab in that dialog and click the Help button for details.

Perhaps this is where you are setting the values?  If so, consider this just additional info for later readers rather than an answer.

See [#If...Then...#Else Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262671%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

VB6 executable sizes are padded to 4KB blocks, so if the code difference is small it will make no difference to the executable.